# How to manipulate data in View using Asp.Net Mvc RC 2?

Tags: data-structures, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a table [Users] with the following columns:
  INT      SmallDateTime   Bit     Bit
[UserId], [BirthDate], [Gender], [Active]

Gender and Active are Bit that hold either 0 or 1.

I am displaying this data in a table on my View.

1. For the Gender I want to display
   'Male' or 'Female', **how** and **where** do
   I manipulate the 1's and 0's? Is it done in the repository where I fetch the data or in the View?
2. For the Active column I want to show
   a checkBox that will AutoPostBack on selection change
   and update the Active filed in the
   Database. How is this done without
   Ajax or jQuery?

Comment: Can you post what you've come up so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Question #1:

Use a DisplayTemplate. In View/Shared create a folder named DisplayTemplates. Then Add a partial View to  this folder named Gender.ascx. Make sure it is not strongly typed.

the markup in this file will look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Boolean>" %>
<span><%= Model ? "Male" : "Female" %></span>
```

Then in your Model you decorate the Gender property with a UIHint thusly:

```
[UIHint("Gender")]
public boolean Gender { get; set; }
```

In your View you make it use this template by using DisplayFor

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender) %>
```

If you cannot use the UIHint you can explicity name your template in DisplayFor

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender, "Gender") %>
```